# Checking "Use Default Value" box programmatically

Tags: magento-1.9

I need to check "Use Default Value" box for product status programmatically.

I found [this](https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/33371/51693) answer.
So to untick the box I could use this code:

```
$product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($productId);
                    $product->setData($args['row']);
                    $product->setStoreId($storeid);
                    $product->setData('status', true);
                    $product->save();
```

The problem I encountered was, that if I untick the box like this, the status would always change to "Enabled" and that is obviously because of `$product->setData('status', true);`

I want the status to remain as it was (like it would when manually unticking the box), so I made a change to the code:

```
    $actualstatusvalue = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->setStoreId($storeid)->load($productId)->getData('status');
    $product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($productId);
                          $product->setData($args['row']);
                          $product->setStoreId($storeid);
                          $product->setData('status', true);
                          $product->setData('status', $actualstatusvalue);
                          $product->save();
```

So I set the status back to what it was before unticking the box.

This does what I need, but since I don't understand exactly how this works (specifically `$product->setData($args['row']);`), I am worried that this is a silly/stupid way of doing it.

Comment: Why are you doing `$product->setData($args['row']);` in the first place?