# Unable to change product URL key?

Tags: magento-1.7, url, url-rewrite, product-urls

Our catalog staff accidentally changed URL key so we have to revert it back to original.

We have changed and updated the product URL key to its original value: [image]

And flushed both Index and Cache Storage. However [the wrong URL](https://www.princessly.com/princess-ivory-lace-blush-pink-tulle-flower-girl-dress.html) is still being used but the [updated URL key](https://www.princessly.com/ivory-lace-blush-pink-tulle-flower-girl-dress.html) is not working.

Why? It's really weird. What are we doing wrong here?

## Update

[image]
After some tests, it seems updating the URL Key of the product only affects the URL rewrites of the **French** store view but NOT the **Default store view**. However I update the URL key, the URL rewrite of the Default store view stays the same. Why?

Comment: Hi. Have you checked in Url Rewrite Management in admin?

Comment: @Raj No but ain't that automatically managed? Do we have to manually update things there to change the URL key?

Comment: Mostly after doing reindexing it should be work. Try reindexing using ssh.

Comment: @Raj I included the rewrites details of this product. What is wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

Try creating custom url for this product in url rewrite management in admin.
But first you have to delete old default url for this product (for both store).

Answer (score 0):

For some reason I don't know, the default store view is using its own url key value. So I used this solution to delete all product values for the default store view so they fall back to default values:

https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/33373/3029

After deleting all the specific product values for the default store view, including the url key, now the url key is correctly using the default value rather than its own store view value.